# Django model - One of foreigners set as main

Tags: python, django, model

I have simple model in Django:

```
class ClientEmail(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField('E-mail')
    default_email = models.BooleanField('Default e-mail')
```

How to make that only one of foreigners for client can be set as deafult?
How to keep one of foreigners always set as deafult, even after deleting this one which is already set as default?

Comment: could you add extra information as it's not clear what your aim is?

Comment: I want to have one email always set as default, even when I delete currently marked as deafult I want other one to become dafault

Comment: how do you decide which one becomes the default when you delete the current default?

Comment: First one of the rest of phones. I am trying to achieve this with signals, is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using signals, I don't know if it's proper way, let me know if not.

```
@receiver(
    post_delete,
    sender=ClientPhone,
    dispatch_uid="keep_one_client_phone_as_deafult"
)
def keep_one_default_phone_after_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    phones = sender.objects.filter(client_id=instance.client_id)
    if len(phones) == 0:
        return
    elif len(phones) == 1:
        if not phones[0].default:
            phones[0].default = True
            phones[0].save()
            return
    else:
        if instance.default:
            sender.objects.get(client_id=instance.client_id).update(default=True)


@receiver(
    post_save,
    sender=ClientEmail,
    dispatch_uid="keep_one_client_email_as_deafult"
)
def keep_one_default_email(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    emails = sender.objects.filter(client_id=instance.client_id)
    if len(emails) == 0:
        return
    elif len(emails) == 1:
        if not emails[0].default:
            emails[0].default = True
            emails[0].save()
            return
    else:
        if instance.default:
            sender.objects.filter(
                ~Q(id=instance.id),
                client_id=instance.client_id
                ).update(default=False)
        else:
            emails[0].default = True
            emails[0].save()
```

Is it good approach to use signals in Django like this? Or should I extend model's default save and edit functions?